# ASP .NET Identity Owin PasswordSignInAsync Method Sometimes Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

When i try to login with the PasswordSignInAsync method, sometimes it returns Failure even though the user informations are correct. **I press the login button wait for the result and if it didn't work i press it again and so on. It generally works in the third try**. We're using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin v2.2.1. Here is our code:

```
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

So i thought maybe there was a problem with the async method and i changed it to `PasswordSignIn` and the method signature for this version was `public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)`. But still it has the same result.

You may asking it should be username not email in the method in our project **usernames are equal to the emails**. But i put `username` instead of `email` from the user model just to be sure. But the result still is same.

I don't know if the version we are using has this bug or if we are missing something.

PS: This a .NET MVC project.

Edit: Here is my OWIN configuration:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(DbContextFactory.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {

            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

       app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    }
```

Comment: @M-Aktas. Could you post your OWIN configuration? I code OWIN identity in the past. As I remember, it uses redirection with http 302 status code. So multiple Login button clicks may interfere with OWIN process and you will receive such website behavior you are describing above.

Comment: @yW0K5o Hi, I posted my OWIN configs. Could you check it again? My English is not very well so i think i misexplained the case. I don't press login button repedately before getting and a result. What i do is i press login button once, then wait for the result as "Invalid login attempt", then i press it again and wait for the result as well. Then i press it once again and it works. But sometimes it works at the first time.

Comment: @M-Aktas. Try Fiddler to capture http/s traffic `https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler`